# End date must be after start date (jquery for noobs)

Tags: jquery, validation, date

I'm having a heck of a time wrapping my head around JQuery syntax (probably because my javascript isn't that solid to begin with).  Here's my problem. I'm using datepicker on two input boxes (`#ev_start` and `#ev_end`)  `#ev_end` must occur after `#ev_start`.

HTML

```
Event Start <input type='text' name='ev_start' id='ev_start'/>
Event End   <input type='text' name='ev_end' id='ev_start'/>
```

JQuery that works

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    //DATE/TIME INFO
    $.datepicker.setDefaults({ dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd', firstDay: 1  });

    $(function() {
        $("#ev_start").datepicker({showOn: 'button', 
                                   buttonImage: 'images/jquery_ui/calendar.gif', 
                                   buttonImageOnly: true
                                 });
    });

    $(function() {//display Calendar
        $("#ev_end").datepicker({showOn: 'button', 
                                 buttonImage: 'images/jquery_ui/calendar.gif', 
                                 buttonImageOnly: true
                                });
});
```

JQuery that is supposed to set the mindate on ev_end's datepicker, but doesn't:

```
$("#ev_start").live('blur',
                    function(){
                      $('#ev_end').datepicker('option', 'minDate', $('#ev_start').datepicker( 'getDate' ))
                    });//inside the $(document).ready(function())
```

I'm hoping someone can explain *both* why the the above doesn't work and what would work and why.

Thanks!

Comment: One thing, could be a typo but you probably need to start with `$("#ev_start")` rather than `$("ev_start")`

Comment: good eye! I've fixed the typo

Comment: but the typo wasn't the issue, unfortunately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is to modify the datepicker for #ev_end in the initial function:

```
$(function() {//display Calendar
    $("#ev_end").datepicker({showOn: 'both', 
                             buttonImage: 'images/jquery_ui/calendar.gif', 
                             buttonImageOnly: true,
                             beforeShow: function() { 
                                var d=$("#ev_start").datepicker('getDate');
                                if(d) return {minDate: d}
                                }
                            });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot do that with some jQuery built-in method. It's a possible solution to make you own method to check that.